# add values to list based index of another list python

Tags: python, indexing

I have the following list:

```
list1=[2,3,5,9,12]
```

And another list which is an index to positions of `list1`

```
list2=[1,3]
```

I would like to add `2` to the positional values of `list1` indexed in `list2`

The output should be

```
[2,4,5,12,12]
```

I was thinking in a loop

```
for value in list2:
    list1[value]+2
```

However no changes are made in list1 and I am sure there should be a 1 line way to do this.

Comment: You need to assign the new value to `list1[value]`

Comment: You want `+=` instead of just `+`

Comment: Shouldn't your expected output be [2,5,5,11,12]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is:

```
>>> for value in list2:
...     list1[value] += 2
...
>>> list1
[2, 5, 5, 11, 12]
```

`+=` is syntactic sugar for `list1[value] = list1[value] + 2`. When you use `list1[value] + 2` what happens is that Python evaluates first the value of `list1[value]` and then adds 2 to it but this value is not stored anywhere.

Another way is to use list comprehension:

```
>>> list1=[2,3,5,9,12]
>>> list2=[1,3]
>>> list_final = [value + 2 if index in list2 else value for index, value in enumerate(list1)]
>>> list_final
[2, 5, 5, 11, 12]
```

Here

```
list_final = [value + 2 if index in list2 else value for index, value in enumerate(list1)]
```

we construct a new list, `list_final`, that basically uses `enumerate` to create a list of tuples containing pairs of values and their indices in `list1`. From there we add to the new list `value + 2` if the index of that value is in `list2` otherwise the plain value.

Comment: There is a difference between the 2 ways you suggest. The first one is iteration over list2 and the second one is iterating over list1. Since list1 contains more elements it would be better to loop over the shorter list which is list2

Comment: You are correct, @balderman, it was more to show an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed to assign the value here:

```py
    list1[value]+2
```

That computes the value you want, but it doesn't change what's stored in `list1[value]`.
You can use `=` or `+=` to assign the result of your computation.